# Closed form expression for the 2-Wasserstein distance between generalized Gaussian distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, optimization, distance-functions, wasserstein

Essentially the title - is there a closed form expression for the [2-Wasserstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) (aka Frechet distance, Earth Mover's distance) between two [generalized Gaussian distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution)? The regular Gaussian case is well known, but I am interested in the generalized Gaussian case, or even mixture of Gaussian distributions.

Comment: Hi Shashank. Welcome to CV. Did you find anything of your own on this? If so, please mention your research efforts.